# How to provide my custom certificate when using MSMQ?

Tags: c#, wcf, certificate, msmq, netmsmqbinding

Is there any nice step by step tutorial on using external certificates in MSMQ ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about these MSDN pages?

[Message Authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms707003(VS.85).aspx)

[C-C++ Code Example: Requesting Authentication Using an External Certificate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms704095(v=vs.85).aspx)